# Xpath to display text values

Tags: xpath, text

I am trying to write an XPATH to show an Item number, but I can only figure out how to display the text 'Item Number (DPCI)', not the actual item number, which would be 085-03-7859 in the example below

```
<div>
 <b>Item Number (DPCI)</b>
 ":"
 "085-03-7859"
 <hr aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

[image]

I tried `//b[text()='Item Number (DPCI)']` but it only shows: Item Number (DPCI)

Comment: How does the XML or HTML input look? The inspector screenshot looks odd with two adjacent text nodes ": " and that number. If the colon is part of the content of the `div` container I would simply select the `div` (perhaps with a predicate `//div[b = 'Item Number (DPCI)']`) and use `substring-after` e.g. `substring-after(//div[b = 'Item Number (DPCI)'], ': ')`.

Comment: Thank you so much, your suggestion works!  I had never used 'substring-after' and will certainly keep it in mind.  Agreed, the inspector was odd and it was throwing me off.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You want to address the `text()` node that is a child of the `div` that has a `b` who's `text()` is "Item Number (DCPI)".

The XPath you were using addresses the `b` element. So, you could modify your XPath to start from there and then look for the `text()` sibling:

```
//b[text()='Item Number (DPCI)']/following-sibling::text()
```

There are some empty `text()`, so you would want to exclude those. You can do that with another predicate that tests if `normalize-space()` (which collapses whitespace characters and removes whitespace-only) selects anything:

```
//div[b ='Item Number (DPCI)']/text()[normalize-space()]
```

That will give you:

```
":"
"085-03-7859"
```

So, now you want to parse the phone number from within that `text()`. You can use `normalize-space()` again to "flatten out" that string, and then use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` to get between those quotes:

```
substring-before(
  substring-after(
    normalize-space(//div[b ='Item Number (DPCI)']/text()[normalize-space()]), 
    '&quot;:&quot; &quot;'), 
  '&quot;')
```

Comment: I really appreciate your detailed explanation, I am very new at this but eager to learn so all the new information helps.  I actually add [2] to your first suggestion and it worked! //b[text()='Item Number (DPCI)']/following-sibling::text()[2]

Comment: @lwfish, just curious, what kind of environment is that? The needed use of `following-sibling::text()[2]` indeed suggests there are two separate but adjacent text nodes for the `: ` and the number. That normally doesn't happen if lexical input is parsed by an XML or HTML parser, I can only imagine that some JavaScript code inserted/appended first a text node with `: ` and then a second with that number.

Comment: Martin, it is from target.com, I don't know enough about the rest of your question to answer properly!  I am in product development for big box retail, so learning how to write xpaths to use a web scraping software to gather data.

Comment: The first text node is a whitespace-only node (carriage return before the `b`` and the "real text" following that). That's why I had the predicate using normalize-space() to filter that out.